# Decidablility Turing machine

Tags: turing-machines

Is it decidable whether a Turing machine takes more than 481 steps for some input?

This was asked in one of the exams. I found some solutions but are not clear to me.

Comment: So you think every algo is O(1)?

Comment: How is this related to the question I posted?

Answer (score 1):

In $481$ steps the Turing machine can't look at more than the first $481$ positions on the input tape.  Therefore, just simulate the first $481$ steps for each of the possibilities for the contents of those positions of the input tape...

Comment: There are $2^{481}$ possible contents. For each these input strings the Turing machine is simulated. If for some input it takes more than 481 steps , accept. Whats the rejection criterion?

Comment: Reject if, after trying all possible inputs, you haven't accepted.